# How to rewrite a UNION sql query so it starts with SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an annoying issue that the this sql I need to write without UNION

```
(SELECT entry_id, url_title, channel_id, entry_date, title 
 FROM exp_channel_titles 
 WHERE exp_channel_titles.channel_id = 5 
   AND status = 'open' 
 ORDER BY entry_date asc 
 LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT entry_id, url_title, channel_id, entry_date, title 
 FROM exp_channel_titles 
 WHERE exp_channel_titles.channel_id = 6 
   AND status = 'open'
   AND entry_date > ((unix_timestamp(Now()))+(2*86400))
 ORDER BY entry_date asc LIMIT 1)
UNION
    (SELECT entry_id, url_title, channel_id, entry_date, title
    FROM exp_channel_titles
    WHERE exp_channel_titles.channel_id = 5
    AND status = 'open'
    ORDER BY entry_date asc LIMIT 1,2)
    LIMIT 3;
```

So what it does is select 2 news stories then an event in the future "story" then if no event story add another news story.

So two categories, but one has a different select, so weighted there is always 3 but if possible an event.

I need to think of a way to do this with joins, or starting without the () brackets, to make it simpler. Where I load it does not like UNION.

Comment: can you provide use with an sql export of the relevant tables (creation and data) this way people can work on helping you much easier

Comment: You dont need the brackets now

Comment: Wrap the whole thing with `SELECT * FROM ( .... )`?

Comment: Added answer below, as needed many SELECT adding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the end needed extra SELECT and AS alias to each subquery

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT entry_id, url_title, channel_id, entry_date, title
        FROM exp_channel_titles
        WHERE channel_id = 5
        AND status = 'open'
        ORDER BY entry_date asc LIMIT 2) 
    AS news
UNION
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT entry_id, url_title, channel_id, entry_date, title
        FROM exp_channel_titles
        WHERE channel_id = 6
        AND status = 'open'
        AND entry_date > ((unix_timestamp(Now()))+(2*86400))
        ORDER BY entry_date asc LIMIT 1) 
    AS gallery
UNION 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT entry_id, url_title, channel_id, entry_date, title
        FROM exp_channel_titles
        WHERE channel_id = 5
        AND status = 'open'
        ORDER BY entry_date asc LIMIT 1,2) 
    AS more_news
) AS articles LIMIT 3;
```

Seems MySQL when you wrap () with a SELECT * it now needs to join them differently so each () needs to now be SELECT * FROM () AS alias , which is a bit overkill, but makes sense as it wants to make all cols available.

I would still like a lighter solution as this is a lot of steps, but it works, so good with me.

Comment: Thanks to @Luis Siquot and trincot for direction

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax:

```
select * from (SELECT entry_id, url_title, channel_id, entry_date, title, 1 as comesFrom 
 FROM exp_channel_titles 
 WHERE exp_channel_titles.channel_id = 5 
   AND status = 'open' 
 ORDER BY entry_date asc 
 LIMIT 2) AS part1
UNION
select * from (SELECT entry_id, url_title, channel_id, entry_date, title, 2 as comesFrom
 FROM exp_channel_titles 
 WHERE exp_channel_titles.channel_id = 6 
   AND status = 'open'
   AND entry_date > ((unix_timestamp(Now()))+(2*86400))
 ORDER BY entry_date asc LIMIT 1) as part2
UNION
select * from  (SELECT entry_id, url_title, channel_id, entry_date, title, 3 as comesFrom
    FROM exp_channel_titles
    WHERE exp_channel_titles.channel_id = 5
    AND status = 'open'
    ORDER BY entry_date asc LIMIT 1,2) as part3
-- may be you want an order by here also
LIMIT 3;
```

I did also add a comesFrom field as a flag to know in the final recordset where the particular record comes from. It is useful in some cases.

Comment: sorry, i have no enough english skills to explain the details

Comment: Thanks I love that idea. Had not thought of it. Will try in the morning. And select it it works.

Comment: It was the right direction but MySQL required extra SELECT and AS alias for each sub ()

Comment: yes, thats happens when someone writes querys on the air. I hope you can accept the answer anyway